# How to convert this function to an inline call

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I have the following function to scale a (2-col) matrix:

```
(define (scale-matrix matrix scale)
  (map (lambda (row)
         (list (* scale (car row))
               (* scale (cadr row))))
       matrix))

(scale-matrix '((1 2) (3 4)) 3)
; ((3 6) (9 12))
```

However, I'm having a hard time converting it into an inline curried call. Here is where I am at so far:

```
(map
 (lambda (row)
   (lambda (scale)
     (list (* scale (car row))
           (* scale (cadr row)))))
 '((1 2) (3 4)))
; (#<procedure:...esktop/sicp/021.scm:54:3> #<procedure:...esktop/sicp/021.scm:54:3>)
```

What would be the proper way to pass both the scale and matrix here? In other words, where to put the `3` ?

The closest I've gotten thus far is to sort of hardocde the `3` in there:

```
(map
 (lambda (row)
   ((lambda (scale)
      ; 3 hardcoded, nil placeholder. How to actually 'call' with 3?
      (list (* 3 (car row)) (* 3 (cadr row)))) nil)) 
 '((1 2) (3 4)))
```

Or, is it required that I pass the `scale` as the first argument? It seems to work that way, though not sure if that's required (or even why that works!)

```
((lambda (scale)
  (map (lambda (row)
         (list (* scale (car row)) (* scale (cadr row))))
         '((1 2) (3 4)))) 3)

; ((3 6) (9 12))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last attempt is correct: you'll have to extract the `lambda` used for `scale` *outside* the `map` call. You can't modify the innermost lambda, `map` expects a `lambda` with one argument, you can't pass a nested `lambda` there. So if you want to curry the `scale` there's no option but:

```
((lambda (scale)
   (map (lambda (row)
          (list (* scale (car row))
                (* scale (cadr row))))
        '((1 2) (3 4))))
 3)
=> '((3 6) (9 12))
```

As to *why* it works, it's like any other anonymous `lambda` call. Let's see a simpler example, this:

```
(define (add1 n)
  (+ 1 n))

(add1 41)
```

When evaluated is equivalent to this:

```
((lambda (n)
   (+ 1 n))
 41)
```

Incidentally, the above is also how a `let` is expanded and evaluated:

```
(let ((n 41))
  (+ 1 n))
```

So you could also inline the code as shown below; but why do you want to curry it, anyway? the original code with the procedure is just right.

```
(let ((scale 3))
  (map (lambda (row)
         (list (* scale (car row))
               (* scale (cadr row))))
       '((1 2) (3 4))))
```

Comment: thanks for this. As to why, I was just playing around with currying and trying to learn how that works.